# find path with largest sum in grid moving downwards from top row towards bottom

Tags: java, recursion

I am doing a recursion chapter problem from the book "Java illuminated". I am required to find the path with the largest sum in a rectangular grid of positive integers, starting from anywhere in the top row, and moving either directly down or diagonally down in each subsequent step.

So far I have been able to compute the actual sum of the largest path. In the following grid

```
02 05 17 12 03
15 08 04 11 10
09 18 06 20 16
14 13 12 01 07
```

my existing code will return 60.

How can I return (or print out) the PATH with the largest sum? i.e. 17+11+20+12 = 60

```
public class MaximumPath {

    public static int maxSum(int grid[][]){
        int r = grid.length - 1;        // bottom row #
        int c = grid[0].length - 1;     // rightmost column #
        int max = 0;
        for (int i=0; i <= c; i++){
            int val = maxSum(grid, r, i); // call recursive method for each of the bottom row cells
            if ( val > max) max = val;
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static int maxSum(int grid[][], int row, int col)
    // recursive method to find largest sum path to row,col, coming downwards from top
    {
       if (col < 0 || row < 0 || row > grid[0].length || col > grid.length) return 0;      
       else return grid[row][col] + max3(   maxSum(grid, row-1, col-1),         // top left
                                            maxSum(grid, row-1, col),           // top
                                            maxSum(grid, row-1, col+1) ) ;      // top right
    }

    public static int max3(int x, int y, int z) // return max of 3 numbers
    {
       if (x > y)
          return (x > z)? x : z;
       else
          return (y > z)? y : z;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] grid = {{2, 5, 17, 12, 3}, 
                        {15, 8, 4, 11, 10}, 
                        {9, 18, 6, 20, 16}, 
                        {14, 13, 12, 1, 7}};
        System.out.println("Max sum is "+maxSum(grid));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you don't know which path is the correct one until right at the end, due to the nature of the recursion. So you have to store each path as you go (including the total), only keeping the largest ones at each row comparison.

Here is a quick solution I whipped up:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MaximumPath {

    // object to store both path and total
    public static class Pair {
        public ArrayList a;
        public int b;

        public Pair(ArrayList a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    };

    public static Pair maxSum(int grid[][]){
        int r = grid.length - 1;        // bottom row #
        int c = grid[0].length - 1;     // rightmost column #
        Pair max = null;
        for (int i=0; i <= c; i++){
            Pair val = maxSum(grid, r, i); // call recursive method for each of the bottom row cells
            if (max == null || val.b > max.b) max = val;
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static Pair maxSum(int grid[][], int row, int col)
    // recursive method to find largest sum path to row,col, coming downwards from top
    {
       if (col < 0 || row < 0 || row > grid[0].length || col > grid.length){           
           return new Pair(new ArrayList(), 0);           
       }else{
           // take the path pair with the max value so far
           Pair p = maxPair(maxSum(grid, row-1, col-1),         // top left
                            maxSum(grid, row-1, col),           // top
                            maxSum(grid, row-1, col+1) ) ;      // top right)            
           // add the current path value and total to the path
           p.a.add(grid[row][col]);
           p.b += grid[row][col];           
           return p;
       }       
    }

    public static Pair maxPair(Pair x, Pair y, Pair z)
    {
        if(x.b > y.b){
            return (x.b > z.b)? x : z;
        }else{
            return (y.b > z.b)? y : z;   
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] grid = {{2, 5, 17, 12, 3}, 
                        {15, 8, 4, 11, 10}, 
                        {9, 18, 6, 20, 16}, 
                        {14, 13, 12, 1, 7}};    
        Pair p = maxSum(grid);
        System.out.println("Max sum is " + p.b);
        System.out.println("Path is " + p.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect - I tried placing several System.out.println at various places to debug how the recursion was working but was unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic programming problem.  You need to find the [Maximum Subarray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Wiki covers the algorithm in one dimension.  Once you understand this, its pretty easy to extend to 2 dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. The wiki entry gave me the clue I needed an array like numbers{} to store the path.